# Redirection rules S3 with ansible

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

I'm quite new to ansible and awscli. I'm tring to play a role to create a bucket as website with index. Everything is ok but i would like to create also the Redirection Rules.

With an aws cli command like:

```
 - name: Create Bucket
   command: aws s3api create-bucket --bucket myskroto --acl public-read-write  --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-west-1
   become: yes
```

i'm able to create the desired task but inside ansible i receive an error about finding the bucket.js file. **Where should i put this file?**

```
 Unable to load paramfile file://bucket.js: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bucket.js'"
```

Tring instead to use an asnible module like:

```
- name: Configure an s3 bucket as a website with index and error pages
  s3_website:
    name: myskroto
    suffix: index.html
    error_key: errors/404.htm
    state: present
```

everything is ok but i'm not able to populate the Redirection Rules. Which parameter can i use?

Thanks
:)

Comment: Your ansible task declaration is not valid. Please double check and fix it.

Comment: the ansible task is working (maybe is not well formatted here) the problem is i would like to populate the Redirection Rules

Comment: As you wrote it, it cannot work. It will give a yaml syntax error. You should edit your question and fix it so that people comming here to help you have the correct info and can make sure your problem is not related to a side effect.

Comment: Ok now it's the same identation i run. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The problem was simply i was calling bucket.js instead of bucket.json.
Everything is fixed. I put the file in the same main.yml root.

```
test_ansible_roles/
├── bucket.json
├── ec2instances
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── defaults
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── handlers
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── meta
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── tasks
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── inventory
│   │   └── test.yml
│   └── vars
│       └── main.yml
├── main.yml
└── s3bucket
    ├── README.md
    ├── defaults
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── handlers
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── meta
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── tasks
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── tests
    │   ├── inventory
    │   └── test.yml
    └── vars
        └── main.yml
```